# blank email generated from php form

Tags: php, email-attachments

I have the below code which is executed when someone hits a send button on a form.

My issue is I am receiving an email with the correct subject line and from/to email address. However if the email contains an attachment the body then is blank. However if their is no email attachment the email body gets populated with the text the user would of typed in.

I should note I understand that the code is not as safe as in its current state does not limit inappropriate files like exe's from being uploaded. However I am not wanting or needing a lesson in how to make the code safe. I just need help with how/why the text body does not get populated when an attachment is uploaded?

```
     <?php
         //send email
          if(isset($_POST['sendemail']))
            {
              $txtSid = md5(uniqid(time()));
              $emailsubject = $_POST['emailsubject'];
              $emailpriority = $_POST['emailpriority'];
              $emailto = $_POST['emailto'];
              $emailcc = $_POST['cc'];
              $emailbcc = $_POST['bcc'];
              $txtFilesName = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];
              $emailbody = $_POST['wysiwg_editor'];

              //if their is an attachment add notice in body of email
               if($txtFilesName !='')
                  {
                    $emailbody = "$emailbody <br /><br />File name $txtFilesName attached to this email.";
                  }                                           

$headers = "From: $my_fname $my_lname <$my_emailaddr>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $my_fname $my_lname <$my_emailaddr>\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: $emailcc\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: $emailbcc\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$txtSid."\"\n\n";
$headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";
$headers .= $emailbody."\n\n";

if($emailpriority == 'high priority')
 {
   $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n";
   $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
   $headers .= "Importance: High\n";
 }


   $headers .= "--".$txtSid."\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";


/***********Email Attachment************/
if($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] != "")
{
    $txtFilesName = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];
    $txtContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"]))); 
    $headers .= "--".$txtSid."\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$txtFilesName."\"\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$txtFilesName."\"\n\n";
    $headers .= $txtContent."\n\n";
}


mail("$emailto","$emailsubject","$emailbody","$headers");


echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Email Sent!</div>";
}
```

---

OK I re-copy and pasted the code I am using and it has fixed my issue. It seems that I needed a $headers .= $emailbody."\n\n"; line of code inside the if email attachment section.

Comment: Are there any errors in your PHP logs?

Comment: I do not see anything in my error logs. Usually if their is an error in my root directory I will have a error_log.txt file that will help me but I don't seem to have one for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Under the if statement that detects if there is an attachment uploaded, you are not combining the previous emailbody and the notice together. Instead, use this code:

```
$emailbody = $emailbody."<br /><br />File name ".$txtFilesName." attached to this email.";
```